# How to we replace log(0) with 0?

Tags: numpy

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply`

I have a code:

```
a = Y_list * np.log(Y_list/E_Y)
print(a)
```

My `Y_list` contains `0` values, I'm wondering how to do when `Y_list = 0` , `np.log(0) = 0`?

Comment: The logarithm of 0 in any base is undefined. Not zero.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply! im actually doing a school assignment and they require such a condition..'If Y = 0, the expression log[Y/(E(Y))] will be taken as zero'

Comment: are Y_list and E_Y numpy arrays? you can use np.where or an inline if depending on the answer.

Comment: yup both are numpy arrays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) It lets you define a condition for true and false and assign different values.

```
np.where((Y_list/E_Y)!= 0, np.log(Y_list/E_Y),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, we can run `np.log` with a `where` parameter:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0, 5000, 1000)
np.log(a, where=a != 0)

# array([0.        , 6.90775528, 7.60090246, 8.00636757, 8.29404964])
```